# Arithmetic Progressions Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, education, regular-expressions

I'm studying progressions in math class **in Portugal**, and I don't know the words/translation in english for certain things so I'll try to explain.

I have this arithmetic progression: 2, 8, 18, 32 ...

I want to know the 5th term. Is there a formula to know the *general term*(the formula to know any of the terms) without the reason(r)? I read online that:
Un = U1 + (n-1) * r

r is the difference between Un+1 and Un. (Un+1 - Un)

In this progression though, the r changes, so I'm guessing I can't use that formula.

Comment: If you write your question in Portuguese, someone may answer in Portuguese, or may translate your question into English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true arithmetic progression does follow the rule $U_n=U_1+(n-1)r$, so this is not an arithmetic progression.  There is no general rule for finding the general term of a sequence.  If the sequence is the list of values of a polynomial, taking the difference of successive terms will result in a constant eventually.  In your case:$$2\quad 8 \quad 18 \quad 32 \\ \ \ 6 \quad 10 \quad 14 \\ \quad 4 \quad 4$$ We now *assume* that the $4$'s continue.  The fact that it takes two sets of differences says the polynomial is of second degree.  The leading term is the final difference divided by the factorial of the degree, so here $\frac 4{2!}=2$ and the leading term of he polynomial is $2n^2$  You can subtract that off from the values to get a polynomial of one degree lower.  In this case that is all there is.

Comment: Thanks for that method! I had the answer 2n^2 though (from class), I wanted to know how to. Although now that I look at it it's wrong U1 = 2*1^2 = 2^2 = 4. (Answer below is right though) I think in class I didn't hear it well, teacher must've said 2n^2/2

Comment: $2n^2$ is correct.  $U_1=2=2 \cdot 1^2$

Comment: Doesn't the first term 2*1^2 equal 4?

Comment: @RAO:  No, only the $1$ is squared. $2\cdot 1^2$ should be read $2 \cdot (1^2)=2 \cdot 1=2$, just as $2n^2=2(n^2)$  Exponentiation before multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to acquire general term

By writing sequence recursively we have
$$\begin{align}a_1&=2\\
a_2&=a_1+(6+4(1-1))=8\\
a_3&=a_2+(6+4(3-2))=18\\
a_4&=a_3+(6+4(4-2))=32\\
\vdots\\
a_n&=a_{n-1}+(6+4(n-2))\\
a_n&=2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(6+4(k-2))}
\end{align}$$
(By summing all steps)

$$a_n=2+2(n-1)+4\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

$$a_n=\frac{4+4(n-1)+4n(n-1)}{2}$$

$$a_n=\frac{4+4n-4+4n^2-4n}{2}=\frac{4n^2}{2}=2n^2$$

General term of this sequence is

> $$2n^2$$